# Writing Hindi language on UILabel in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

I have written a code where I need to display hindi numbers on the UILabel. I used devanagari font to show that value but it doesn't work. It just changes the look but not the language.

I was using:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DevanagariSangamMN" size:16];
myLabel.font = font;
```

But it's not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You have got the font name wrong. The font name is `DevanagariSangamMN` not `DevanagarSangamMN` (note the missing 'i' in your name). Your code should therefore be:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DevanagariSangamMN" size:16]; 
myLabel.font = font;
```

To find more information about the iOS Fonts. I recommend [this](http://iosfonts.com/) website which has all the fonts available in iOS

Also, if you type English characters into the Label, you will get returned the English version NOT the Hindi translation. It doesn't do the translation for you. Using the DevanagariSangamMN only allows you to show the Hindi Characters because the fonts such as Helvetica which are normally used do not include the Hindi glyphs. For example:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DevanagariSangamMN" size:16]; 
myLabel.font = font;
myLabel.text = @"Testing";
```

This will return 'Testing' in English, Not in Hindi. However if you do:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DevanagariSangamMN" size:16]; 
myLabel.font = font;
myLabel.text = @"परीक्षण";
```

Then you will get 'परीक्षण' which is the Hindi for 'Testing' (I used Google Translate so it could be wrong). So to get the number '4' with the Hindi version (४), you need to do the following:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DevanagariSangamMN" size:16]; 
myLabel.font = font;
myLabel.text = @"४";
```

Comment: Yes I'm using same font. DevanagariSangamMN I made mistake write writing question. So I'm using it like myLable.text = @"4"; and then assigning font but it doesn't work. Can you please help?

Comment: Ok, but actually I'm adding two numbers and then I'm getting result. So for that there is no way i can directly get the translation? I'll manually need to write all the numbers???

Comment: You could define the numbers from 1 to 9 and then change each number to the hindi variation but yes you would need to.

Comment: Thanks, i want to know that can i use multiple fonts for single UITextView. actually i am loading doc file on UITextView. But only english text is coming properly in textView. Other text like sanskrit and hindi text is not coming in a readable format so how can i write hindi and sanskrit text on my UITextView ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it can shows परीक्षण without assigning any new font, simply assigning this text to label works without need of settings font

Answer (score 1):

are you assigning your `UILabel` text in unicode? Try this -

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String with unicode %C", 0x207F];
```

Comment: Hmm not sure. Any example to print numbers using this?

Comment: numbers in english? why? numbers fall in the ASCII character set. It's hindi, chinese etc. i.e. other foreign languages that are accomodated in unicode...