# how to show sanskrit and hindi characters on text view in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uifont

I am working on a project in which I want to take data from a doc file to a UITextView, that are in English, Sanskrit and Hindi. Only english characters are showing properly in textView. I am getting other sanskrit and hindi character in gibberish (unreadable) format so how can I show hindi and sanskrit text on my UITextView ?

[This is a sample that i want to display in UITextView....

[image]

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513928/writing-hindi-language-on-uilabel-in-xcode

Comment: @RushabhThanks for your reply but i am not getting all text font...

Comment: even we can't use custom fonts in application , because i am getting text from doc file. Now, i am trying to put UIImages for different hindi and sanskrit character and use multiple UITextView for english text....is it correct way to do this?

Comment: in Xcode- beta 10 version UILabelView was able to show Hindi fonts but now I have updated the Xcode to the stable version. the UILabelView is not showing Hindi fonts properly. Can anyone suggest what's the problem? @Rushabh